# Loop into PHP Array, then loop into SQL Insert... or something different... help please

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Lets say I have two tables. In table “category_name”, there are fields category_id and category name. In table “category_subscriptions” there are fields userid and category_number.

What I want to be able to do is to insert a row into category_subscriptions for each category_id using the same userid.

Consider “category_name” having the following values: 4, cars, 5, trucks, 6, trains

The ideal output table for “category_subscriptions (for userid=99) would have values: 99,4,99,5,99,6

Rather than use:

```
INSERT INTO category_subscriptions
VALUES (99,4)

INSERT INTO category_subscriptions
VALUES (99,5)

INSERT INTO category_subscriptions
VALUES (99,6)
```

I think I should be using a loop, as category.id won’t always be 4,5, &6. I’m just not sure if this is right and am hoping somebody can help. This is part of a plugin for Joomla 1.7/php.

Comment: What's the relationship between `category_name` and `category_subscriptions`? Is `category_number` in the latter a reference to `category_id` in the former?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an array `$Categories` including all your `category_id`'s, you can do:

```
$user_id = 99;
$Categories = array(4, 5, 6);

$sql = "INSERT INTO category_subscriptions VALUES ";
$i = 0;
foreach ($Categories as $categorie) {
    if ($i++) $sql .= ", ";
    $sql .= "({$user_id}, {$categorie})";
}
```

The [output](http://codepad.org/5G3VVRBm) of this code is

```
INSERT INTO category_subscriptions VALUES (99, 4), (99, 5), (99, 6)
```

Please note, that this builds a single query. You can insert multiple lines with one `INSERT` statement using `VALUES (<line1>), (<line2>) ...`

**EDIT**

If you really want to link your user to **every** existing category, you can also do it in plain SQL.

```
INSERT INTO `category_subscriptions` (`userid`, `category_number`)
    SELECT 99, `category_id` FROM `category_name`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
<?php
$userID = '99';
$catID = array(4,5,6); 

foreach($catID as $cid) 
{
    $value[] = '('.$userID,$cid.')';
}

mysql_query('INSERT INTO category_subscriptions (user_id,category_id) VALUES '.implode(',', $value));
?>
```

The script above will run mysql query :

```
INSERT INTO category_subscriptions VALUES (99,4), (99,5), (99,6)
```